# Use NodeJS sockets to communicate with sockets in other languages

Tags: node.js, sockets

So basically I want to use NodeJS sockets to create a server as well as clients to speak between each other, my question is if a NodeJS socket can expect data from other languages, for example a socket in C++ send data to my program in NodeJS? I saw examples that always runs express for the server, I need to create the server in the same application. Thanks in advance and excuse my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my question is if a NodeJS socket can expect data from other languages

Yes.  These are just normal network sockets on which you send/receive arbitrary data.  Nothing about them are specific to Node.js

> I saw examples that always runs express for the server

Express is a framework for handling HTTP requests.  HTTP is a protocol that runs on top of a TCP socket.  Express is irrelevant here, unless you want to use HTTP... in which case you'd use Express in conjunction with Node.js' built in HTTP library.

Don't confuse Web Sockets with normal sockets.  They're really unrelated.  Web Sockets are an abstraction on top of HTTP which emulate socket behavior between browsers and servers, but they really have nothing to do with each other, directly.  You can't use a Web Socket client to connect to an arbitrary port on something.

Comment: Your description of webSockets is very odd and misleading.  The connection scheme for a webSocket connection is based on an initial http connection and it has some security stuff built in, but beyond that it's a real TCP socket using a specific data frame format for sending/receiving data.  It's not "emulating" socket behavior at all.  It is a real TCP socket speaking a specific data protocol.

Comment: @jfriend00 Odd and misleading?  Hardly.  Confusion between Web Sockets and regular network sockets happens all the time.  If you don't draw a clear distinction, people assume you can just connect to arbitrary services with their Web Socket client.  The two are unrelated... at completely different layers.

Comment: Well, there's no "emulating" of socket behavior at all.  It's a real TCP socket with the webSocket protocol being used as the protocol.  Your notion of "emulation" is just wrong.  Yes, webSocket is a higher level than a plain TCP socket, but there's no "emulation" of anything happening anywhere.  That part of your answer is wrong and misleading.  You could take a few moments to fix that part of your answer.  webSockets are a layer on top of a regular socket, not a layer on to of HTTP.  They momentarily use HTTP to initiate the connection, but then there's no HTTP after that.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks, I'm aware of how web sockets work. When I say "emulate", I mean that in common use and implementations, you effectively get a full duplex stream for sending arbitrary data over... the same sort of behavior you would get over a regular network socket.  I used to teach a class on this, and have tried out a few high-level explanations of Web Sockets... this one tends to stick. It explains the difference, shows that they aren't related, but explains the naming and similar functional intent. If I was speaking to you or I who already understand, my explanation might be different.

Comment: Then, I disagree with your use of misleading phrases to try to explain this.  Saying that websockets and regular sockets are unrelated is just wrong.  As you know, a websocket is a protocol layer on top of a regular socket.  They aren't unrelated at all.  That would be like saying that HTTP and sockets are unrelated.  It's just wrong AND misleading.

Comment: You're welcome to disagree.  I would say that HTTP and sockets are *fundamentally* unrelated.  They're two entirely different things on different layers of abstraction.  Sure, you'll use HTTP over a socket, just like you drive a car on a road, but I'm not going to take my broken car transmission to a pavement expert.  Naming is important, and I think Web Socket was a poor name choice.  Beginners immediately get confused with Web Sockets and regular network sockets, and that confusion tends to mess them up for months if the difference isn't immediately made very clear.

Comment: To clarify, I completely understand where you're coming from... all I'm saying is that beginners don't typically understand the slight overloading of terms, so this is something that needs some extra emphasis.  This is the best I know how to do it when giving a high-level overview, and the explanation has been proven to work for beginners.

Answer (score -2):

> sockets to create a server as well as clients to speak between each other

You, sir, need [socket.io](http://www.socket.io)

Comment: The OP does not need socket.io at all.  That would be one option, but you can also do exactly what they  asked for and create a plain TCP socket in node.js using the NET module.  That socket will have nothing node.js specific in it and can communicate with any other client/server written in any language that uses a plain TCP socket.  socket.io is not needed to do that.  socket.io is a protocol that runs on top of TCP and is useful for some things (such as message passing), but isn't needed to speak to other languages.

Comment: Oh, well, TIL. Sorry for passing incorrect information, I should've phrased it differently it was an option ;)